# Sencha Touch Reading remote XML data

Tags: xml, ajax, list, sencha-touch

I have just recently started working with Sencha Touch 2.1. I am having problem in reading XML data.When reading local xml file, it works fine on PC,phone and tablet;When reading remote xml,it works fine on PC,but I have a blank list on phone and tablet.What am I missing?

Model

```
    Ext.define('Cus.model.Biz', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
        {name: 'tel', type: 'auto'},
        {name: 'address', type: 'auto'}
    ]
}
```

});

Store

```
Ext.define("Cus.store.BizList", {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['Cus.model.Biz', 'Ext.data.reader.Xml'],
config: {
    model: 'Cus.model.Biz',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url:'http://ip:port/XXX/list.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'Result',
            record: 'Biz'
        }
    }
}
```

});

View

```
Ext.define('Cus.view.phone.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
requires:[
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'Cus.store.BizList'
],

config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'My List',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: 'BizList',
            loadingText: 'loading',
            itemTpl: '{name} {tel} {address}',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

});

and the remote xml file is

```
<Result>
<Bizs>
    <Biz>
        <name>name1</name>
        <tel>tel1</tel>
        <address>add1</address>
    </Biz>
    <Biz>
        <name>name2</name>
        <tel>tel2</tel>
        <address>add2</address>
    </Biz>
    <Biz>
        <name>name3</name>
        <tel>tel3</tel>
        <address>add3</address>
    </Biz>
</Bizs>
```

Comment: Just add on load listener to your store and check your console log to see if data is loaded or not.`listeners:{
         load: function( me, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){ console.log(records); } }` Also let us know what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

It was necessary to define the rights of the requests. in xcode settings or in manifest.xml (for android)